# Grails unit test about new some class using Spock testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

My method is:

```
def client = new SOAPClient("http://...")
def response = client.send(
    """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
       <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
           <soap-env:Body>
               <GetFoo>bar</GetFoo>
           </soap-env:Body>
       </soap-env:Envelope>"""
)
return response.httpResponse.statusCode
```

SOAPClient is a plugin for Grails.

So in my unit test, how can I mock SOAPClient and its send method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def client = Mock(SOAPClient)
client.send(_) >> response
```

Of course you need to create desired response object first.

Comment: By the way, are there any idea how to mock response object? As there will be some dynamic properties for response object. For example, in the service i will have some method like: response.xmlElement1.xmlElement2.xmlElement3....

Comment: The easiest you can do is: `[xmlElement1:'your value', xmlElement2:'other value'] as ResponseClass` (don't remember actual class returned by SOAPClient but us the same behind 'as' operator). If that won't suit your case, you can still use Spock's Mock() method or just simply create response by instantiating it with 'new' operator.